# Asp.net mvc 2 - Error redirecting from ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What changed from mvc1 and mvc2?  I have the following code that redirects to a login page if the user has not been authenticated.  This doesn't work with mvc2 and results in "System.Web.HttpException: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent"

```
public class RequiresAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      string redirectOnSuccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
      string redirectUrl = string.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess);
      string loginUrl = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl;
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
    }
  }
}
```

A stack track is as follows:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
  at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
  at System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__11()
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass14.<>c__DisplayClass16.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__13()
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: Generally, you *don't* redirect in `OnAuthorization`. ASP.NET already does that for you. But, then again, MVC already handles authorization, too, with any provider you care to use or write. It's hard to say what you ***should*** do without knowing how much of this you intend to rewrite and why. Generally, I think that developers are *way* too eager to rewrite ASP.NET authentication, and tend to do it incorrectly. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/ The right way to redirect on authorization failure is to set the URI in `web.config`.

Comment: The site was originally written around mvc1 preview 2, before the AuthorizeAttribute was created.  I honestly wasn't aware that attribute existed until this problem started coming up.  I'll have a look and see if it solves what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is override HandleUnauthorizedRequest instead of OnAuthorization and just assign the RedirectResult url to the AuthorizationContext.Result.

The base.OnAuthorization will check authentication and call HandleUnauthorizedRequest if it fails.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    string redirectOnSuccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    string redirectUrl = string.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess);
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Excellent - this helped me too.  I had filterContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl), which seemed to work, but was throwing errors in the background.  Thanks